# iOS Xcode project won't build/run when the Run button is clicked

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm looking at examples at Cocoa Controls and have downloaded some demos. The issue that I've ran into is that some examples, like [BCTabBarController](https://github.com/briancollins/BCTabBarController), won't build or launch on my device. When I open the project, it looks normal, there are no missing files or errors. But when I click the "Play" button in Xcode, nothing happens. There is a very fast "build" animation, but the app never starts on the device, and the "stop" button is not enabled.

**Has anyone ran into the issue where nothing happens when the "Play" button is tapped in Xcode?** How did you fix the project settings to make it build?

Comment: try cleaning the build command+shift+K along with changing the deployment target and do check the provisioning profile.

Comment: clean your code... And check whether it works on simulator.. If it does check for provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

Change your manage schemes...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In this specific project you can change the manage scheme to `Example` and run it.(just click on the project name next to the stop button and select Example). But, Not all projects on github provide an example that you can just run & play. Nothing happens because nothing is suppose to happen. If you want to test a project out that doesn't have an example usually you should follow the instructions on the GitHub ReadMe.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me with Xcode 9.4. **Quitting Xcode** and [**deleting the DerivedData folder**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38016143/3151675) solved the problem for me.