# How can I delete derived data in Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

The projects page seems to be disappeared from Xcode 8. I used this page for deleting the derived data.

Any idea how can I delete derived data from within Xcode 8?

Comment: Download WatchDog for Mac if you’re using Xcode a lot - automates the process.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Many different solutions for this problem. Most of them work as well.
Another shortcut seems to be added as well:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Will ask you to:

> **Are you sure you want to clean the build folder for “MyProject”?**
>
> This will delete all of the products and intermediate files in the build folder.

In most cases this would be enough to solve your problems.

**UPDATE**

As of Xcode 9 you'll be able to access the Derived Data folder by navigating to

*File -> Project Settings*

or if you use a Workspace:

*File -> Workspace Settings*

And press the arrow behind the path:
[image]

Comment: After press the arrow, dont forget to first quit the XCode, and after that delete that folder from finder

Comment: ⌘⇧K  will clean your projects build folder but ⌥⌘⇧K will clean it immediately without warning

Answer (score 478):

(Working in Xcode 11, 12, 13, 14, and 15)

You can go to `File` > `Workspace Settings` if you are in a workspace environment or `File` > `Project Settings` for a regular project environment.

Then click over the little grey arrow under `Derived data` section and select your project folder to delete it.

[image: Click that button]

Comment: or `File` > `Playground Settings` if you are in a playground

Comment: For xCode 13 works as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 263):

The simplest and fastest way is the following (if you have not changed the defaults folder for DerivedData).

Open terminal and past the following:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Comment: As an additional beneficial option, you can also delete all app builds on all of your simulators by running the following (once you've quit running any simulators) `xcrun simctl erase all`. This doesn't clear the same stuff as derivate data obviously, but if you're trying to free up space this is another great option, as both take up quite a bit for old app builds.

Comment: You could also make this a terminal shortcut. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/375092/how-to-set-up-a-shortcut-to-a-directory-in-mac-os-x-terminal/375126#375126)

Comment: But this also deletes the folder itself! Is that not a problem?

Comment: @user5306470 it is not, XCode will recreate it when needed.

Answer (score 92):

In Xcode 8, all the derived data is automatically cleaned. If you want to do it by hand, go to `Locations` tab from the `Preferences`, locate project's derived data folder, and delete files related to the project.

> In macOS 10.12 and later, Xcode cleans up stale derived data,
>   precompiled headers, and module caches. (23282174)
>
> *[Xcode 8.0
>    Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW90)*

Credits to @charmingToad

But from what I observed, the same behaviour is typical when using Xcode 8 on OS X 10.11.5/6

Comment: Do you have a reference to where this is specified?

Comment: is there an official source that confirm this that it is automatically cleaned?

Comment: Automatically cleaned when?

Comment: deleting this and cleaning your project fixed my problem in Xcode 8 when every project got stuck on 'compiling asset catalogs'

Comment: Xcode 8 release notes say "In macOS 10.12 and later, Xcode cleans up stale derived data, precompiled headers, and module caches." I'm not sure how often derived data is considered "stale" though... https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html

Comment: @dmzza not sure to be honest, Apple doesn't explain when it does it.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on this (I got a compiler still looking for a deleted file without any reference to it in the project). So manually wiping it still can be a very good idea.

Comment: I can confirm i just had to delete Derived Data to get a new framework added to the Firebase module.

Answer (score 71):

**Go to** `Xcode` -> `Project Settings`

[image]

**You can find the way to go to derived Data**

[image]

Comment: With a bit more of text/context into this answer... this should be the one selected. Adding screenshots it's always a huge plus.

Comment: Note that it will say "Workspace Settings" if you're using a .xcworkspace file instead of an .xcproject file. Caught me off guard for a second

Comment: After click the arrow, quit the XCode, and after that delete folder from finder

Comment: Nicely explained. @Nazik

Comment: without these remarks this solution would not work, please add them to your answer

Answer (score 60):

**Method 1:**

- Close Xcode
- Open Terminal and enter this command

  ```
  rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
  ```

**Method 2:**

- Click on Xcode menu
- Go to Preference
- Select Locations (as shown in image)
- Click on the arrow below the Derived Data (as shown in image).

It will bring you to the location of derived data and you can just delete it manually.

[image]

Comment: Note that if you get an error saying a subfolder of the derived data directory could not be deleted because it's not empty (even when you run with `-rf`), you need to quit XCode and your simulator and then try again to clear the derived data

Answer (score 55):

## Manual removal of derived data

If you want to remove derived data manually just run:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

If you want to free up more disk space there's a few other directories you might want to clear out as well though.

## Automatic removal of Xcode generated files

I have created a Bash script for removing all kinds of files generated by Xcode. Removing DerivedData content can be done by running:

```
./xcode-clean.sh -d
```

More info at https://github.com/niklasberglund/xcode-clean.sh

Comment: Why might someone want to delete `Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport`?

Comment: [SO answered already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930198/can-i-delete-data-from-the-ios-devicesupport-directory?rq=1). Thanks for posting this script.

Answer (score 23):

In your terminal :

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Answer (score 12):

In the Latest Xcode version 12+ Follow the below steps, I found here https://handyopinion.com/solution-failed-to-load-info-plist-from-bundle-at-path-in-xcode/

**1.**

[image]

**2.**

[image]

It will navigate to the Derived Data folder then you can remove the content of the folder.

Answer (score 11):

Select Xcode and Follow 4 steps that highlighted in photo and remove derived data then restart your project.[image]

Answer (score 10):

Another way to go to your derived data folder is by right click on your App under "Products" folder in xcode and click "Show in Finder".

Comment: This won't work if you've set your product to a different path -- for example, I set mine to build straight to ~/Applications, but keep the derived data in the default location.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the root of the project using terminal and then paste the below mentioned line

**rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData**

Once it is executed, you can verify by going to Xcode > Preference > Locations -> Tap arrow shows ["DeriveData"] end point.

Comment: You don't need to go to the root of the project since the command uses an absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

**Steps For Delete DerivedData:**

1. Open Finder
2. From menu click on `Go` > `Go to Folder`
3. Enter **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData** in textfield
4. Click on `Go` button
5. You will see the folders of your `Xcode projects`
6. `Delete` the folders of projects, which you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a bash command. Configure it with 3 simple steps. then in the terminal just type `cleandd`
https://github.com/Salarsoleimani/Usefulscripts

Answer (score 0):

It may differ between versions of xcodes. Best approach is to go xcode preference page and from tab "Locations", directly open "Derived Data" directory.

Answer (score 0):

DevCleaner on the Mac App Store did the trick for me!

https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/devcleaner-for-xcode/id1388020431?mt=12

Also looks useful for removing other cruft due to Xcode. Remember this is a 3rd party app so usual trust warnings apply.

Answer (score 0):

To delete derived data in Xcode 8, follow below steps:

1. Open Xcode 8 and go to the "Preferences" menu.
2. Click on the "Locations" tab.
3. Look for the "Derived Data" section and click on the small arrow icon next to the path.
4. This will open the "DerivedData" folder in Finder.
5. Quit Xcode 8 to avoid any conflicts.
6. Select all the folders inside the "DerivedData" folder and move them to the trash.
7. Empty the trash to permanently delete the derived data.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Derived data & Cache for Xcode :
Simply Do

1. Run command on terminal : Delete Derived data

**rm -frd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***

2. Delete Cache data : Xcode

**rm -frd ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/***

Answer (score -11):

For Xcode Version 8.2 (8C38), you can remove the projects completely (project name in Xcode, programs, data, etc.) one by one by doing the following: [Note: the instructions are not for just remove the project names from the Welcome Window]

Launch the Xocde and wait until the Welcome window is displayed. The projects will be shown on the right hand side (see below) [Xcode Welcome Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B62Q.png)

Right click the project you want to remove completely and a pop window [Show in Folder] jumps out; selec it to find out where is the project in the [Finder] (see below) [Find the project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gukRf.png)

Right click the project folder in the Finder to find it’s path through [Get Info]; use path in the Info window to go to the parent folder, and go to there[Locate the project folder path] (see below)

Right click the Project Folder (e.g. DemoProject01) and Porject file (DemoProject01.xcodeproj) and select [Move to Trash] ; you will see that (a) the folder in finder is removed AND (b) the Project in the Xcode Welcome Window’s Project List is removed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the deletion of `Derived Data` folder content.