# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) with Swift 3

Tags: xcode, linker-errors, build-error, swift3, xcode8

I am working on building a Swift library and am [hosting it on GitHub](https://github.com/Napalm-Framework/Napalm).

All was going fine until I added [BluetoothKit](https://github.com/rhummelmose/BluetoothKit) to the project. I then got an Apple Mach-O Linker Error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
ld: /Users/calebklevetertest/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Napalm-dblvhbjdwovurocsvzrzaxzkjjyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Napalm.framework/Napalm compiled with older version of Swift language (2.0) than previous files (3.0) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

From reading the error it appears the issue somehow stems from the fact I am using Swift 3, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I did convert BluetoothKit to Swift 3 when I added it.

There is one class that uses BluetoothKit and it is called `NPFBluetooth`.

A couple things to note are 1) Even though the class is public, the compiler gives an error of 'unresolved identifier', 2) The class does not show in the auto-complete and 3) All the other classes work fine.

Comment: I know this is frequently a useless suggestion but, have you tried deleting derived data and rebuilding?

Comment: @PhillipMills, That actually fixed it! Thanks! However, the warning still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the error migrating to swift3. As it turns out Xcode keeps copies of built frameworks and moving to swift3 is apparently not a cue to rebuild those (even after finding out it was built using swift2.... no let's throw a vague error instead...)

The solution is to [delete the content of your 'derived data' folder.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8)

Works for frameworks installed with Carthage and cocoapods.....

Answer (score 0):

Go to your build settings and switch the target's settings to ENABLE_BITCODE = YES for now.
It's working for me ;)