# CocoaPods in xCode 8 Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: xcode, cocoa, linker, frameworks

I'm trying to implement Alamofire in a Cocoa Touch Framework and use this framework in a different xCode project for reuse
I'm getting the following error: "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

reproduce steps:

1. create a Cocoa Touch Framework project in xCode
2. pod init in the terminal
3. add pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.3' to the Podfile
4. pod install in the terminal
5. open the xcworkspace and compile - build is success
6. create a Single View Application in xCode
7. compile - build is success
8. add the xcodeproj of the first project (I can't add the xcworkspace)
9. add the .framework file to the second project Embedded Binaries

   10. compile - build is failed with the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) with Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226316/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-with-swift-3)

Comment: Try deleting your derived data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8