# Sticker pack extension loading on simulator on iPhone 7, but not 7+ or iPad pro?

Tags: ios, swift, imessage

My sticker pack works fine in the simulator with the iPhone 7, but with the iPhone 7+ or iPad Pro, the application isn't available when I open iMessage and click for apps? It feels like a simulator bug?

Comment: [Clearing Derived Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8) fixes it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I had quit Xcode several times, but restarting finally fixed this.  FYI