# 'Parse/ParseClientConfiguration.h' file not found

Tags: swift, parse-platform, back4app

I am trying to make a project using Parse. My project used to work before Swift 3.0 update. Yesterday I decided to upgrade my project code to Swift 3.0. I also updated Parse to its latest version which I used pods to do it. I get these 2 errors which I couldn't find a solution to. I deleted Parse and then reinstalled again using Pods but that didn't fix the problem.

(Can't post pictures because I don't have enough reputation :/)
(Can't post more than 2 links too :/)

Error #1:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K6TU.png

Error #2:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAcex.png

Proof of having the required file:

These are the 2 errors that I am encountering right now. When I remove the ParseClientConfiguration.h I also get the same error twice.

Error #1 twice:

While answering keep in mind that I am not a very experienced programmer. You may have to explain some parts more detailed. If you need more information I would gladly provide them.

Comment: Proof of having the required file: http://imgur.com/5fjWjyR 

Error #1 twice: http://imgur.com/oRZGXtB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting "Derived Data" solved my problem.

How to delete "Derived Data":

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495772/7188022

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you ran into this, because you ignored

> "From now on you’ll open the workspace file instead of the project file"

**like I did.**

A single line, which can easily bee overseen at the [Install Guide](https://www.back4app.com/docs/ios/parse-swift-sdk)