# Xcode 8.1 takes too long for indexing and compiling using Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, xcode8

why does Xcode 8.x takes too long for indexing and compiling using Swift 3.0? Sometimes it won't stop loading. It's annoying for me, because it keeps me from continuing in my project. I've got many swift files (around 50 files).

By the way are there any good practices in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this stems from DerivedData if you have:

1. Too many source compilations
2. Many pseudo instructions

The best option is to delete the derived data ([How to delete Derived Data in XCode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40278559/7202136))