# Events from storyboard don't reach view controller

Tags: ios, swift3

(Newbie question) after mucking around with renaming folders/modules, etc. I find that events are no longer triggered. Looking in the story board inspector, all events look to be wired properly.

But no events are triggered in the view controller.

How can this be debugged? Could it be something wrong with the module names, relative paths or anything like that.

Code snippets:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, STBackgroundTaskDelegate, MeshViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
```

viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // ... more here...
}
```

Receiving method:

```
@IBAction func overlayTypeChangedWithSender(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    NSLog("Overlay type changed")
    showOverlay()
}
```

Comment: We need some code otherwise we are not able to help you.

Comment: Make sure The Module field in your Identity Inspector is pointing to your new module names in storyboard

Comment: Sulthan - I don't know what code to post. It wouldn't make much sense to post complete storyboard and ViewController,  would it?

Comment: sheetal - As far as I can tell, the module field has the correct module name (same as in file tree on the left).

Comment: @DennisThrysøe Yes. You can for example post the minimal reproducible code to github and share it with us.

Comment: @DennisThrysøe Show your storyboard Image and UI image.

Comment: I don't know how to make a minimum reproducible code set. I cannot publish the entire project, which would be needed for compilation. I could share the storyboard and ViewController files - would that be sufficient?

Comment: What would screenshots need to contain, in order to be helpful?

Comment: @DennisThrysøe Knowing what changes did you do (file renaming? moving between folders? anything else? specifics) might help, also some examples of what types of events are failing

Comment: @Tony mainly I changed a folder (package?) name. In the filesystem, and also in some XML files.

Answer (score 1):

You may have forgotten to change the `Custom Class` in Storyboard or Xcode caches outdated data. Do the following:

- Copy the `NameOfViewController` to the `Custom Class` field for your viewController in Storyboard.
- Clean the project (Product -> Clean)
- Clear Derived Data. [Here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495772/1457385).
- Restart Xcode
- Build & Run

Comment: These steps did unfortunately not solve the issue. But thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting another control in one of your problem classes?  If you can do that, have a look at the connections inspector for the new control, and earlier ones in the same view - they SHOULD be connected to the same class (of course), but if they are not, you just need to remove the old connection and reconnect

Comment: I tried with several controls, none of them work. I removed and re-added all connections, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: So you definitely have the right connection between your class file and the View Controller -  or you wouldn't be able to attach new outlets...

What events are failing?  Do you need delegates to be set up, or is it even failing for simple actions on buttons, for instance?

Comment: Yes, failing for buttons and UISegmentedControl.

Comment: You need to show us the code - all the declarations at the top of the UIViewController file, `viewDidLoad` and the actions you have set up.

Comment: I added some code. Hope it helps. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: What is `overlayTypeChangedWithSender`?  Is it one of your custom methods?  Where do you set this up as an action?  What delegate is it related to?

Comment: Yes, this is a custom method. It is configured in the storyboard to receive the event (and it used to work, at least for some of the buttons; I am not 100% sure when it stopped working, but I assume it relates to changing around some names).