# Cannot find protocol declaration for UIScrollViewDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uiscrollviewdelegate

Whenever I try to compile my Xcode project I get error cannot find protocol declaration for `UIScrollViewDelegate`

I have cleaned my project multiple times but nothing seems to solve the issue.

Also I have an error could not build module `UIKit` I am unable to fix the issue for long as my project does not build.

Comment: can you show you full code ?

Comment: it is a big project so showing code is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to build `UIKit` again, [Clean derived data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495772/1457385)).

Once it has been build the delegate will be found also.

Comment: Please post the target you build against (iPhone 6 Simulator, 10.1 for instance) and your Deployment Target. Try if other combinations work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you haven't made any changes in `Foundation framework` accidentally!!! I mean in any class of `UIKit`!!

If above is not the case then `full clean and deleting derived data` should work!

You couldn't building `UIKIt` so you are unable to find `UIScrollViewDelegate` I think, but it's depends on another cases also!

Answer (score 0):

Try following may be it will help:

1. Removing and adding `UIKit.framework` in `Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries`.
2. Check that you have not typed anything or modified anything in `UIKit.framework` header files.

   May be in `UIKit.framework`-->`Headers`-->`UIScrollView.h` in your case.