# Iphone 5 cannot run with "arvm7s", but similator do

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, device

I have this problem with running app on my iPhone 5.

I has just figure that if i use `layout.estimatedItemSize` in my code then my app will crash on  my iPhone 5, and at the first time build for it, Xcode said that `the device cannot run executables for armv7s`

When I delete `layout.estimatedItemSize`, all work fine?

Can someone help me about this?

Comment: What is the crash log?

Comment: hi, it's just say nil crash @@

Comment: I use on Simulator, Iphone 5 Simulator iOS 10, it's all fine, but my Iphone 5, iOS 9 don't

Comment: Clean project and derived data. If the issue persists, try if building for another configuration (Release/Debug) or optimization level (None/Fastest) changes the behaviour.

Comment: how to clean derived data ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39495772