# Strange "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11" error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I've converted my project from Swift 2 to Swift 3 and since then I get an error message - `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`.

The error log is:

```
<built-in>:1:1: note: in module 'GoogleMaps' imported from <built-in>:2:
#define __llvm__ 1
^
/Users/myMac/Documents/me/MyProject/MyProject Rewrite/MyProject/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Headers/GMSCoordinateBounds+GoogleMaps.h:24:12: warning: duplicate definition of category 'GoogleMaps' on interface 'GMSCoordinateBounds'
@interface GMSCoordinateBounds (GoogleMaps)
           ^
/Users/myMac/Documents/me/MyProject/MyProject Rewrite/MyProject/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Headers/GMSCoordinateBounds+GoogleMaps.h:24:12: note: previous definition is here
@interface GMSCoordinateBounds (GoogleMaps)

                                           #selector(getter: UIPreviewActionItem.title)
0  swift                    0x0000000107cc23ad PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45
1  swift                    0x0000000107cc1b56 SignalHandler(int) + 790
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fffa8802b3a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fa637658e30 _sigtramp + 2397397776
4  swift                    0x00000001052beaf3 swift::Lowering::TypeConverter::getFunctionInterfaceTypeWithCaptures(swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::AnyFunctionType>, swift::AnyFunctionRef) + 67
5  swift                    0x00000001052c0b58 swift::Lowering::TypeConverter::makeConstantInterfaceType(swift::SILDeclRef) + 872
6  swift                    0x0000000105270845 swift::Lowering::TypeConverter::getConstantInfo(swift::SILDeclRef) + 165
7  swift                    0x0000000105271106 swift::Lowering::TypeConverter::getConstantSelfParameter(swift::SILDeclRef) + 38
8  swift                    0x0000000104f15cce (anonymous namespace)::AccessorBasedComponent<swift::Lowering::PhysicalPathComponent>::getBaseAccessKind(swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction&, swift::AccessKind) const + 30
9  swift                    0x0000000104f20ae9 drillToLastComponent(swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction&, swift::SILLocation, swift::Lowering::LValue&&, swift::Lowering::ManagedValue&, swift::AccessKind) + 137
10 swift                    0x0000000104f22933 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitLoadOfLValue(swift::SILLocation, swift::Lowering::LValue&&, swift::Lowering::SGFContext, bool) + 227
11 swift                    0x0000000104ef389d swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::RValueEmitter, swift::Lowering::RValue, void, void, void, void, void, swift::Lowering::SGFContext>::visit(swift::Expr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 20557
12 swift                    0x0000000104f4efaa swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitReturnExpr(swift::SILLocation, swift::Expr*) + 506
13 swift                    0x0000000104f4b7d7 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtEmitter, void, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 183
14 swift                    0x0000000104f4c6d6 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtEmitter, void, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 4022
15 swift                    0x0000000104f0ce1a swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitFunction(swift::FuncDecl*) + 314
16 swift                    0x0000000104e89055 swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitFunction(swift::FuncDecl*)::$_1::operator()(swift::SILFunction*) const + 1877
17 swift                    0x0000000104e87c02 swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitFunction(swift::FuncDecl*) + 626
18 swift                    0x0000000104f53777 (anonymous namespace)::SILGenType::emitType() + 1271
19 swift                    0x0000000104f5320e swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::visitNominalTypeDecl(swift::NominalTypeDecl*) + 30
20 swift                    0x0000000104e94973 swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 1795
21 swift                    0x0000000104e9662d swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILOptions&, swift::FileUnit*, llvm::Optional<unsigned int>, bool, bool) + 1629
22 swift                    0x0000000104ccee86 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 19510
23 swift                    0x0000000104cc82b3 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 17859
24 swift                    0x0000000104c845cf main + 8239
25 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fffa85f3235 start + 1
```

I've tried to figure out what the problem is in the file (it's probably `MarkerInfoWindowController`) but I couldn't understand what happened.

Any idea how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: replace `Selector(...)` with `#selector(...)` and try again?

Comment: @abjurato So it gives me the error `Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer`

Comment: fix this error now, `#selector` does not take string as an argument: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/hannibal-selector/

Comment: @abjurato It seems to change the error, it's the same error with a different log. I've updated the question, can you please take a look? Thanks!

Comment: seems like GoogleMaps breaks compiler... did you try to delete derived data, update pods and build again? (three magic things)

Comment: @abjurato I didn't try it, where can I delete the derived data? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8

Comment: @abjurato I've deleted the files there, closed XCode and run `pod update` in terminal. Still doesn't work. Any other idea?

Comment: could you show code where this `#selector` happens?

Comment: @abjurato Do you mean where `representedObject.responds(to: Selector("title"))` was? I thought we've already solved it... Not the Google Maps is the problem

Comment: but there is still  `#selector(getter: UIPreviewActionItem.title)` line in the middle of error log...

Comment: @abjurato I don't have this line in MY code, maybe in one of the frameworks?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139385/discussion-between-fs-o6-and-abjurato).