# Old App Icon showing in Open In ... menu on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am updating an iOS application.  I have created new App Icons and everything works except the Open In menu.  The Home App Icon is correct, the App Icon in Settings is correct, but the App Icon in the Open In menu is the old App Icon.

My UTI document type shows the new small icon on the attachment.

Anybody know where the old App Icon is hiding?

Thanks, Allen

Comment: I am not using Xamarin and have the same problem. Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: @Luke try my answer. If it not work then provide me your demo code

Answer (score 6):

When you enabled the application to show up in Open in...menu for the first time, you provided a separate icon as per [this apple guide and samples](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html).

In Step 6, you add the icon separately.

Have you tried removing (-) the icon and add (+) a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

- In iPhone, delete the app
- In Xcode, [clean derived data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40278559/584548)
- Reinstall the app

It looks like the icon is somehow cached.

Comment: I am using Xamarin for this app.  Is there a way to clean derived data in Xamarin?

Comment: I have looked in the bundle and there is no png with the old icon that I can see

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed you are using Xamarin. In that case, I have no idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to update all the icon sizes. 
There are multiple icon sizes depending on the DPI of the screen. You may have only updated the @2x size and have left the regular size, or vice versa.

Check all icon sizes.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/app-icons/

Answer (score 0):

you write the **App Icon in Settings is correct**, but I don't know if in Xamarin there is another setting or you mean the info.plist, please check for App Icons - Source : AppIcon, should look like this

[image]

if this doesn't help can you, please try to delete the application from device, clean the project if its possible, close xamarin and try the process again.

Hope this should work.

Comment: In my case (not using Xamarin), this setting is correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your app using Assets as your icons, just check icons in iOS\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\
2. If Assets icons are correct, please check the icons in iTunes Connect
3. Check iTunes Artwork

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `Resources` folder, there is a chance that you might be using an image from resource in your code.

Also If you are using asset catalog then you should have `Images.xcassets` folder under which there will be 2 other folders: `AppIcons.appiconset` and `LaunchImages.launchimage` inside this folder you should have `Contents.json` file open this file and re check your icons.

Additionally clean and build your project `(Build -> Clean All)`, also if you are using `Xcode`, clean `Xcode (Product -> clean)` and try again.

Comment: The old icon is not anywhere in the Resources folder or Images.xcassets. Cleaning did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Check AppIcon.appiconset of the application is there anywhere old icon also Check Contents.json file all icon are mentioned properly or not.

If you have used UIDocumentInteractionController then check

this [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller/1616801-icons)

Check your Info.plist . Is UTI icon declared properly in Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

To add the document type do the following:

```
1 - In your Xcode project, select the target you want to add the document type to.
2 - Select the Info tab.
3 - Click on the disclosure button for Document Types to open the document types.
4 - Click the “+” button.
5 - In the newly created document type :
6 - Type the name of the document type.
7 - In the “Types” section fill in the UTI for the new type.
8 - Provide an icon for the document.
9 - Click the disclosure triangle to open Additional document type properties.
10 - Click in the table to add a new key and value.
11 - For the key value type: CFBundleTypeRole.
12 - For the value type: Editor.
13 - Click the + button to add another key/value pair.
14 - For the key value type: LSHandlerRank.
15 -For the value type: Owner.
```

check this question [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204893)

Comment: Your steps above are exactly as in the in Lucy's `link` below.  Except for the renumbering. Her step 6 below is your step 8.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin, make sure your info.plist is pointing to the right spot (eg: `<string>Resources/Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>` if it's in the resources folder, or `<string>Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>` if it's in the root folder), and make sure the media.xcassets folder is included in your project (that was my mistake)