# Apple Mach-O Linker Error in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift3, linker

I am trying to build my Xcode project, but I'm getting an error saying `Apple Mach-O Linker Error`

Here's what the error says:

> Ld
>   /Users/jordanbaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialMediaAppThing-efwjgynvqfyiotcrqqssiwhsryyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocialMediaAppThing.app/SocialMediaAppThing
>   normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/jordanbaron/Desktop/SocialMediaAppThing
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.2
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/jordanbaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialMediaAppThing-efwjgynvqfyiotcrqqssiwhsryyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/jordanbaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialMediaAppThing-efwjgynvqfyiotcrqqssiwhsryyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/jordanbaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialMediaAppThing-efwjgynvqfyiotcrqqssiwhsryyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher
>   -F/Users/jordanbaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialMediaAppThing-efwjgynvqfyiotcrqqssiwhsryyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac
>   -F/Users/jordanbaron/Desktop/SocialMediaAppThing/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/jordanbaron/Desktop/SocialMediaAppThing/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/jordanbaron/Desktop/SocialMediaAppThing/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/jordanbaron/Desktop/SocialMediaAppThing/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks
>   -filelist /Users/jordanbaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialMediaAppThing-efwjgynvqfyiotcrqqssiwhsryyw/Build/Intermediates/SocialMediaAppThing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocialMediaAppThing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SocialMediaAppThing.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=10.2
>   -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/jordanbaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialMediaAppThing-efwjgynvqfyiotcrqqssiwhsryyw/Build/Intermediates/SocialMediaAppThing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocialMediaAppThing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SocialMediaAppThing_lto.o
>   -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
>   -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/jordanbaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialMediaAppThing-efwjgynvqfyiotcrqqssiwhsryyw/Build/Intermediates/SocialMediaAppThing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocialMediaAppThing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SocialMediaAppThing.swiftmodule
>   -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseInstanceID
>   -framework GTMSessionFetcher -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -Xlinker
>   -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/jordanbaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialMediaAppThing-efwjgynvqfyiotcrqqssiwhsryyw/Build/Intermediates/SocialMediaAppThing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocialMediaAppThing.build/SocialMediaAppThing.app.xcent
>   -framework Pods_SocialMediaAppThing -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jordanbaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialMediaAppThing-efwjgynvqfyiotcrqqssiwhsryyw/Build/Intermediates/SocialMediaAppThing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocialMediaAppThing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SocialMediaAppThing_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/jordanbaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialMediaAppThing-efwjgynvqfyiotcrqqssiwhsryyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocialMediaAppThing.app/SocialMediaAppThing
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/jordanbaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialMediaAppThing-efwjgynvqfyiotcrqqssiwhsryyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/jordanbaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialMediaAppThing-efwjgynvqfyiotcrqqssiwhsryyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac'
>   ld: framework not found GTMSessionFetcher clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Did you try to clean your project and build it ? 
cmd + shift + T and cmd + B

Comment: Seems like cleaning your DerivedData would be a good place to start. To do so, you can follow this [helpful link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8). Best of luck!

Comment: Those don't work :(

Comment: So I am sure you are doing it right, but is there a chance you opened on your .xcproj file in place of your .xcworkspace file if you are using cocoapods?

Comment: I think that was it.

Comment: I don`t know why, but it is not working anymore, now in Xcode 8.3.2

Comment: having the same problem

Comment: i am also having the same problem . before the app was working perfectly fine but after updating to xcode 8.3.2 it is giving me this error and i followed all the solution given here but no use . same issue . let me know if the problem is solved by anyone ...

Comment: Did you ever figure it out @Moxarth, I'm also having this issue now. I just upgraded to 8.3.2

Comment: no , i could not find any . so again i am using xcode 8.2 . because i could not waste more time to find these silly mistakes done by apple . sometimes it is working perfectly fine and then very next time it is not . it should solve by apple soon . this is so irritating for developers that there is not even single stable solution for this kind of errors . hope apple would come up with some ideas to solve this  .

Comment: I know i am late but it may help anyone else later.
 O linker Mostly Occure when you use same names for properties or objectives in two different classes