# Error in start iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I have this strange error if I try to start my app with swift and Xcode 8.3.1

```
[![Command /var/folders/q8/xsjb69r543qf8j755tfbz7_c0000gs/T/AppTranslocation/883968BB-E85A-4535-8FFC-0B6547D83C04/d/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Don't link screenshots. Paste the error. Also where's your question? You have a lot of reputation, you should know better.

Comment: In your error you can see that it can not find the the directory ArduinoHomeKit.

Comment: what is error code and where it crashing ................

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR read the screenshot. Obviously this is a callstack while building the app

Comment: Can you remember what the last thing you changed was, before the error appeared? I find these errors to be ambiguous at the best of times

Comment: I have change the ios Deployment target from ios 9 to ios 10.0

Answer (score 1):

Clear the `/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and clean + build your project.

Comment: open it in Finder and simply remove all subfolders. or move into trash

Comment: I'm trying to do this but not works. I have move to trash all subfolders. Then I have clean and build my project, but when I try to build my project I received the some error

Answer (score 0):

Delete derived data or create a new app and copy/paste. Here is how you delete your derived data:

[How to delete derived data in Xcode 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8)