# iOS Swift how to debug SIGABRT :"fatal error: call of deleted method" from a CocoaPod?

Tags: debugging, swift3, cocoapods, ios9, sigabrt

I have an app which uses [SlideMenuControllerSwift](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift). I've modified some code to see how to present different panels, then rolled back my changes.

When running the project I get `SIGABRT` `fatal error: call of deleted method` in console when `SlideMenuControllerSwift` is initializing. No other error messages are given.

- The project's source control appears to be in exactly the same state as before
  changes.
- I did a "clean"
- Reinstalled pods.
- Deleted pods directory and made a clean install
- Deleted app from device and ran again
- Did a fresh checkout into a different folder
- Updated cocoapods gem
- Even modified the function to use self.addLeftGestures()

**How do I debug an issue caused by cocoa pod throwing "fatal error: call of deleted method"?**

[image]

UPDATE: seems like something is seriously broken with the functions inside that pod, calling another function within init causes bad access exception:

[image]

Comment: Another developer working on the same branch has no issues. I've modified the cocoapod code to avoid calling that function, instead pasting the code right there

Comment: Potential solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8

Comment: I assume you were using pod and then decide to use it as a source but If you have a IBOutlet reference from Interface Builder. u should change its module target to your project target instead of removed pod target.

Comment: Just check Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> In Info section the scheme should be Debug not Release.

Comment: My case was wrong class in IBOutlet

Answer (score 40):

In my case, I had created a project scheme that uses the release build configuration:

[image: Edit Scheme]

In this configuration, if your project build settings does not allow testability in this release mode then setting custom breakpoints or app crashes do not let you debug properly and you are served the `fatal error: call of deleted method`

---

### Solution:

Check the project build settings for "**testability**".

[image: Project Build Settings]

Ensure it is "Yes" for the build configuration you are testing under.

In my case, I temporarily enabled **testability** for **Release** by making it **Yes**.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone seeing this error using SwiftUI on XCode 11.4 and trying to access a property on an `ObservableObject` subclass eg.

```swift
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = ""
}

class ModelSub: Model {}

let model = ModelSub()

// This line causes `fatal error: call of deleted method` on XCode 11.4
$model.name

// Instead do 
model._name.projectedValue
```

See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60155665/xcode-11-4-beta-crash-on-published-property-subscription-whats-going-on?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

For me these steps worked,

1. Reset simulator
2. Delete derived data