# Xcode 11.4 beta crash on @Published property subscription. What's going on?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11.4

I do not know why but my code crashes on this $searchTerm publisher. I have many such publishers in my code and everything else works ok. It only does not work in this new Xcode version and works in previous version. If I commented this line and replace it with _searchTerm.projectedValue it starts working as usuall!

```
 _searchTerm.projectedValue
    //$searchTerm
        .debounce(for: .milliseconds(350), scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
        .flatMap { term in
            self.search(by: term)
        }
        .print("searching")
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .assign(to: \.results, on: self)
        .store(in: &disposables)
```

I have error

> Fatal error: Call of deleted method

Comment: Please file a bug report with Apple if you haven't done so already. Thanks!

Comment: same here! did you file a bug report or rdar. It crashes only with Xcode 11.4

Comment: Thanks for the tip on getting around this, works like a charm! Happens on XCode 11.4.1 as well

Comment: Many facing this since Xcode 11.4. I filed a bugreport. But not (surprise surprise...) no feedback yet

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464226/swift-combine-properties-inheritance-throws-fatal-error-call-of-deleted-method

Answer (score 1):

If `searchTerm` is something declared in your class or its superclass then mark it as `final`. In my experience this fixes this issues all the time.

---

My theory is that Swift can't figure out which field from lookup tables is `$searchTerm` is referring, hence the crash. Where as, marking it as `final` will make it dispatch statically. I'm not sure whether this is actually true or not, if anyone has more knowledge on subject please make a comment and I'll update my answer.