# Swift Combine properties inheritance throws 'Fatal error: Call of deleted method' on Xcode 11.4 beta 2 / iOS 13.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, combine, xcode11.4

I'm trying to using Swift Combine to get the changed event of a property.

I have this class that publish the `isLogged` property

```
class CurrentUser: Account {
    static let me = CurrentUser() //Singleton 

    @Published var isLogged: Bool = false

}
```

that inherit from this other class that publish the `profileImageVersion` property

```
class Account {

    @Published var profileImageVersion: String?

    init(){
       self.profileImageVersion = ""
    }
}
```

I'm trying to subscribe to the published inherit `profileImageVersion` property like this without success!

```
// Subscribe to account image changes
userImageChangedSubscriber = CurrentUser.me.$profileImageVersion.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main).sink(receiveValue: { (imageVersion) in           
       ...
    }
})
```

The error is `Fatal error: Call of deleted method`

if, on the other hand, I subscribe to the `isLogged` property, all Is working fine...

```
// Subscribe to logged changes
userLoggedSubscriber = CurrentUser.me.$isLogged.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main).sink(receiveValue: { (logged) in
   ...
})
```

This error is thrown only on Xcode 11.4 beta 2 / iOS 13.4.
Using Xcode 11.3.1 / 13.3 all is working fine!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Swift how to debug SIGABRT :"fatal error: call of deleted method" from a CocoaPod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051325/ios-swift-how-to-debug-sigabrt-fatal-error-call-of-deleted-method-from-a-coc)

Comment: @JacobRelkin This is not caused by a pod but it's my own code. Do you think I can try to configure XCode with your link? If yes, why?

Comment: Well, I've managed to put provided code parts together and result works as expected. So I assume the issue is not in the provided code. Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2.

Comment: Yes @Asperi! With XCode 11.3.1 / iOS 13.3 I don't get the fatal error and all is working good!

Comment: @BossOz Please file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60155665/xcode-11-4-beta-crash-on-published-property-subscription-whats-going-on. It gives a possible workaround, I think.

Comment: @matt thank you! I don't know how to fix my issue with this

Answer (score 0):

I have this same crash, and as a temporary workaround I found that moving all your published properties to the concrete class you are using will fix the issue. I had a setup like this:

```
class EpisodesViewModel {
  @Published var episodes: [Episode]

  init(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Episode>, context: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil) throws {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

With a subclass of this model that simply gave a fetch request:

```
final class LatestEpisodesViewModel: EpisodesViewModel {
    init() throws {
        try super.init(fetchRequest: Episode.latestFetchRequest())
    }
}
```

By changing my setup to this I was able to fix the crash:

```
class EpisodesViewModel {
    var fetchedEpisodes: [Episode]

    init(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Episode>, context: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil) throws {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

final class LatestEpisodesViewModel: EpisodesViewModel {

    @Published var episodes: [Episode] = []

    override var fetchedEpisodes: [Episode] {
        didSet {
            episodes = fetchedEpisodes
        }
    }

    init() throws {
        try super.init(fetchRequest: Episode.latestFetchRequest())
    }
}
```

This certainly seems like an Apple bug to me, but this got me around the issue in the meantime.

Comment: What’s your xCode version?

Comment: @BossOz Version 11.4 (11E146)

Comment: Try to upgrade. For me is working fine now but I’m using a simple Boolean value.

Answer (score -1):

I have this same crash on Xcode 11.4.1.
I use "Clean Build Folder", build my project again and all works now fine !