# Use unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

My app was working fine and now suddenly Xcode is giving me this error:

> use unresolved identifier cardWasRemoved

```
func addNewCards() {
    countOfCards = countOfCards-1
    if(countOfCards >= 0){
        self.arrayAuthorization.remove(at: dm.objectIndexToRemove)
        cardWasRemoved(removeIndex: dm.objectIndexToRemove)

    }
}
```

And my method implementation is this:

```
open func cardWasRemoved(removeIndex:Int) {
    if layout.newCardShouldAppearOnTheBottom {
        layout.cardDidRemoved(removeIndex)
    } else {
        layout.cardDidRemoved(removeIndex)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is each function located? Evidently the former can't find the latter.

Comment: It is inside TisprCardStackViewControllerDelegate. I have added this method by my self.. But it was working till today just fine @Carcigenicate

Comment: Also, in `cardWasRemoved`, it should be noted that you do the same thing regardless of `newCardShouldAppearOnTheBottom`.

Comment: yeas but why its not identifying by xcode now?

Comment: Without seeing where each function is specifically, it's impossible to say for sure. If they're where they should be, and should be able to see each other, and you haven't changed a trying since it worked last, it may be an IDE caching bug. Try cleaning your IDE.

Comment: I cant open any backup it gives the same issue now,, @Carcigenicate I did clean but still same... whats this :((

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152332/discussion-between-user1960169-and-carcigenicate).

Comment: Revert to a commit where this was working, and think about the differences between that commit and the working copy.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that there are some artifacts for the Debug build configuration (when you try running on a Simulator), and you don't have these artifacts for the Release configuration. Try removing your DerivedData directory: [How to delete derived data in Xcode 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8)

Comment: Thank you so much. So it won't affect my building reviews?

Comment: In semulator also it runs with out any issue. But cant run on device

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't affect anything, however could you please explain what you mean by "building reviews"?

Comment: Oops typo I meant to say reviewing app builds. And You are correct. My app approved just now :) But still cannot run on the device. I will do what you suggested. Thanks again :)

Comment: I tried deleting derived data. But still its giving the same error when I try to run on my device :((