# UIView override func touchesBegan default stub throwing error

Tags: ios, swift

XCode 8.3.3 w/ Swift 3

```
import UIKit

class myview: UIView {
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>?, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // Don't forget to add "?" after Set<UITouch>
}
}
```

All four functions are throwing the error:  "Cannot specialize non generic type "Set".  The same code in beta 6 of Xcode 9 doesn't have the same issue.

Comment: Did you make that code using copy-paste? If yes, then try to type those methods manually and see how the XCode will show you possible methods

Comment: Thank you - I tried that, but same issue.  It seems to be specific to the project.  If I create a new project, it works as expected.  I checked my Swift version - 3.1 .  I cant think of a reason why this would be specific to a given project.

Comment: That's very strange. You can also check an API, where those methods are provided. They should not be different, but I would check them too

Comment: I can't replicate the issue with the same Xcode and Swift versions. Have you tried cleaning the project through Product -> Clean? That might help. If not, sometimes some of my issues have gone away after clearing the derived data folder. Go to Preferences -> Locations, then copy the derived data folder path, go to finder and locate the directory. Inside, try deleting the folder associated with the specific project. Here's a more detailed answer on how to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8

Comment: I cleaned out the build folder and the derived data folder, but that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**This happens because you've declared your own `Set` object somewhere else in your project.**

I know this because I just spent an hour wondering why I was getting this too.

You should rename your existing Set to something else.