# ARKit – Bug in Xcode 9 Beta 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, xcode9beta6

This morning I have updated my Xcode 9 beta 1 to Xcode 9 beta 6. I'm working with ARKit and my application works fine on beta 1 but now, when I run my app I got this error:

```
//
//dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ARConfiguration
//Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/5B74AF4C-011C-45B0-8BAD-DEF3DA7C0DFA/testARKit.app/testARKit
//Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/ARKit.framework/ARKit in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/5B74AF4C-011C-45B0-8BAD-DEF3DA7C0DFA/testARKit.app/testARKit
//
```

It's a SIGABRT on my thread 1

`0 __abort_with_payload`

`->  0x102ba1774 <+8>: b.lo 0x102ba178c <+32>`

`5 _dydl_start`

`->  0x102b751e0 <+68>: mov x16, x0`

Let me know how to fix this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your project: `shift + option + cmd + k`, then remove your [derived data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8) and rebuild project.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I have the same issue except the symbol not found is "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration"

Comment: That's exactly the update that creates the problem.
I tried with iPad 5 after updating to iOS 11, I got the error. I tried with iPhone 7 on iOS 11 beta 4 or 5, same code, no issue. I updated it and I got the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is API change in beta version. Please update Xcode 9 (beta) to Xcode 9 and iOS 11 (beta) to iOS 11. It works for me.

Comment: It dates from 23 days ago ! It's ok now