# autolayout doesn't work in table view

Tags: ios, swift

i am making a header cell in my table view, usually i have no issue with autolayout, and i have given constraints to the image and button like this

[image]

but when i run the app, all images and labels are attached to the left side, i never add leading edges alignment like this

[image]

even if i change the constraints in the interface builder, the result is just exactly the same. it seems that the autolayout doesn't work or disabled for this table view header cell only.

here is the code of the table view controller :

```
class MediaDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var media: Media!
    var currentUser : User!
    var comments = [Comment]()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Photo"

        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = StoryBoard.mediaCellDefaultHeight
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        comments = media.comments
        tableView.reloadData()

    }





    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 + comments.count
        // 1 for the media image detail itself + the number of comments
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            // media row
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StoryBoard.mediaCell, for: indexPath) as! MediaTableViewCell

            cell.currentUser = currentUser
            cell.media = media

            return cell

        } else {
            // comment row
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StoryBoard.commentCell, for: indexPath) as! CommentCell

            cell.comments = comments[indexPath.row - 1]

            return cell


        }



    }


    // to adjust the height of media cell
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return StoryBoard.mediaCellDefaultHeight
    }




    // for media header cell
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StoryBoard.mediaHeaderCell) as! MediaHeaderCell

        cell.currentUser = currentUser
        cell.media = media
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        return cell



    }

    // set media header height
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return StoryBoard.mediaHeaderHeight
    }




}
```

here is the code of the cell :

```
class MediaHeaderCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameButton : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var followButton : UIButton!


    // the currentUser and Media properties below, will be directed from NewsFeed Table View Controller

    var currentUser : User!
    var media : Media! {
        didSet {

            // if there is someone logged in and he posts the media,then updateUI

            if currentUser != nil {
                updateUI()
            }

        }
    }

    var cache = SAMCache.shared()



    func updateUI() {

        profileImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon-defaultAvatar")

        let cacheKey = "\(self.media.createdBy.uid)-headerImage"



        // check, if the image has already been downloaded and cached then just used the image, otherwise download from firebase storage



        if let image = cache?.object(forKey: cacheKey) as? UIImage {

            self.profileImageView.image = image

        } else {
            // they will be closure retain cycle if we use the method below without [weak var], because there are 2 strong reference between Class  and the closure (user - profileImage).

            media.createdBy.downloadProfilePicture { [weak self] (image, error) in


                if let image = image {
                    self?.profileImageView.image = image
                    self?.cache?.setObject(image, forKey: cacheKey)
                } else if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                }


            }
        }




        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.bounds.width / 2.0
        profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        usernameButton.setTitle(media.createdBy.username, for: [])


        followButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        followButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        followButton.layer.borderColor = followButton.tintColor.cgColor
        followButton.layer.masksToBounds = true


        // check the other users are already followed or not, if yes then follow button shall be shoed up

        if currentUser.follows.contains(media.createdBy) || media.createdBy.uid == currentUser.uid {
            followButton.isHidden = true
        } else {
            followButton.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

what went wrong ?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Reopen Xcode and again add constraints.

Comment: thanks Salman, but unfortunately it doens't work :(

Comment: i can't see label in header ....where it is in view hierarchy ?

Comment: It seems like you are working with assitent editor

Comment: sorry for the confussion, my mistake. i give name 'label' for those 2 buttons, but it is actually buttons. yah, it is an assistant editor, just for the screenshot and to show to the constrainsts

Comment: try setting a constant width for the image view

Comment: yes i have set the height and width of the image view https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwqpy.png

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the values to the buttons and the image view?

Comment: Seems like everything is in place. Could you check if autolayouts is enabled for this View??

Comment: Thanks Reddy, how do i check whether the autolayouts is enabled or not?

Comment: In XIB, slectViewcontroller and hit Option+Command+1, you would see file inspector on the right side. On this, you would see Use Auto Layout option under Interface Document Builder. Hope that helps. You should have Both Use autolayout and Use Trait Variations enabled.

Comment: If this does not work, try command+K to clean up the project, Quit the project and simulator and restart everything. Even that does not work, try deleting derived data as well along with cleaning up the project and quitting all the setup. Below is the link to help you on how to delete derived data.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you set the image to the image view of the superclass. Replace `cell.imageView.image = fooImage` with `cell.profileImageView.image = fooImage`.

Comment: thanks dasdom, i have done it right. it seems that all imageview and button align to the left, but i don't know why