# Xcode Distribution Certificate Private Key Not Installed

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, app-distribution

I am trying to Ad-hoc distribute my app. However, when I archive and than try to export it I am getting following screens:
[image]

On this screen, when I click "Manage Certificates" button, I get following screen: 
[image]

I tried to regenerate provision profile on Apple Developer Portal. I generated and downloaded Mobile Provision files and tried to export again the app but I am received the same missing private keys error.

*UPDATE*
I tried to manually sign my app. When I choose "Download Profile" from 'Provisioning Profile'  it gives me following output screen:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I cannot access my old certificate. I do not know where it is.

Comment: everything is in my machine. i updated my OS on Mac and now I do not know where is my private key.

Comment: sorry, but at this point the question is all over the map - I suggest you delete everything and start over - quit Xcode, delete all profiles, remove all certificates from keychain, go to portal and delete all certificates and profiles, and begin from scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should start over.

1. Quit Xcode.
2. Delete *DerivedData* folder.
3. Delete *~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles* folder.
4. In Keychain Access, delete everything related to Apple development.
5. Go to portal in browser and delete all certificates and profiles.

Now start afresh.

Comment: Also keep in mind, just in case this is not clear, that an archive is made with a development profile but the ad hoc export is done with the ad hoc distribution profile.

Comment: How come I can delete all my certificates on portal? There are many different apps live on App Store!

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant. I've got apps on the app store and this is something I do from time to time (at least once a year, in fact). Revoking the certificate won't magically drill thru to the app store and blow up the existing apps.

Comment: I did not delete my keychains but deleted the provisioning profile on Apple Developer Portal and cleared derive data and provisioning profiles folder. Thanks

Comment: Cool! So you didn't actually have to revoke / delete any certificates?

Comment: I revoke provisioning profile on Apple Dev Portal but not any keychain in my device.

Comment: We're having a terminology problem. Certificates are not provisioning profiles. Both are at the portal. So I don't know what you deleted there.

Comment: This answer is the only method that works for me to resolve this problem and it seems that I have to follow all 5 steps religiously to get it work. Just for reference, this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495772/1724059 shows how to delete the DerivedData in the above point 2.

Comment: @CodePlumber Thanks. I actually perform these steps quite routinely, surprisingly often. It's not difficult at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to locate the Xcode-AlternateDSID and Xcode-Token keys in Mac OS's Keychain Access utility. The utility allowed me to change the passwords to the keys after I entered the administrative password for my computer. Then I could use the new passwords when Xcode asked for them. This restored the missing private key for my iOS Distribution Certificate.