# Apple Distribution Certificate - Missing Private Key on Computer that Generated the Request

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I needed to create a new distribution certificate to upload my app to test flight. to do this, I created a certificate request via the keychain access tool. I then went to the Apple developer portal and created a distribution certificate by uploading that request. I then downloaded the certificate and added it to the keychain. When I attempt to upload, I get the missing key message:

"[name] has one Apple Distribution Certificate but its private key is not installed..."

How is this possible if I am on the computer that generated the request?

Comment: @matt I checked the login keychain and it seems like My distribution certificate is pair with a private key. What is a WDR certificate?

Comment: @matt yeah I have those. Am I correct in assuming that the key is needed to create the request? If not, then perhaps the private key is something generated server side and I downloaded once and maybe accidentally deleted? If this is the case, it is at least plausible that the key is missing

Comment: @matt ok now I deliberately selected a key from the key chain and created a request from said key. Same problem. Truly a mystery. Is it possible that only some types (whatever that means) of keys work? My developer certificate was created from a key called "Apple Development..." whereas the certificate in question is being generated by a keyed named "[my name]"

Comment: @matt well the request file is 968 bytes = 7744 bits. Is that an indication of something wrong?

Comment: This seems parallel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462071/xcode-distribution-certificate-private-key-not-installed

Comment: @matt Seems so. The answer essentially says start from scratch. I've seen other answers (sorry can't find the links) that say upgrade xcode, so I'm doing that (which requires upgrading my mac), but will start over if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading xCode fixed the problem. I was on 11.3.x and upgrading to 12.5 completely fixed the issue. I then ran into app bundle id issues (which were easy to fix), which makes me think perhaps xCode was just giving me the wrong error message. Regardless, upgrading fixed the problem.

Comment: As an aside, upgrading xCode was its own chore for me. I had low disk space on my mac and for some reason xCode requires 30+ GB just for the application (never mind its cache) which means I needed to buy an external hard drive and then needed to strategically move data and apps around.