# Xcode 10 - Can't Build React Native Application

Tags: ios, react-native

Since updating the Xcode 10, I cannot build and run my app either on a physical device or on the simulator. I have tried via the terminal and directly through Xcode. What I have tried:

1. Removing my repo and re pulling.
2. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19573
3. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14382
4. https://medium.com/@swyx/if-you-get-a-third-party-config-h-35a3c54e9278
5. [Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461703/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist)
6. ["config.h" file not found in iOS project of React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019066/config-h-file-not-found-in-ios-project-of-react-native)

I do not know what is left to do. I have had all the errors outlined in the above links. the main one that I am having trouble with at the moment is that `config.h does exist` and `cfbundleidentifier", does not exist`.

Comment: React-native upgrade

Comment: @agibson007. I did that.

Comment: You linked to this SO question, but since the answer that worked for me wasn't the accepted one, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51552501/7551248
What worked for me was to run that `./configure` command in the folder mentioned in the link above, and also change the build type to Legacy as indicated by the first Github Issue you linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the instructions layed out in all the links provided, all I needed to do was run `npm audit fix` and it started working.