# No such module SQLite when archiving

Tags: swift3

I am using Xcode 9.2

1) I have copy the SQLite.xcodeproj file into my project.

2) In the ViewController, i used the following

import SQLite

```
Problem:

 when I do the achive ( Product>Archive) , there is a compile error message:

 No such module 'SQLite'

 If I do normal compile : CMB + B, no issue.
```

Please help. What I need to do?

```
Update:

I followed these approaches but all failed. Where went wrong?


1) Shift+Alt+Command+K

 after this, then CMD + B to. compile Same error msg as above.


2) As of Xcode 9 you'll be able to access the Derived Data folder by navigating to

File -> Project Settings 

  press the arrow to go to the DerivedData folder

 I removed it to trash

after this, then CMD + B to. compile Same error msg as above.


3)Open terminal and past the following:

rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

after this, then CMD + B to. compile Same error msg as above.


Update:

I realized the SQLite is older version before I upgraded to Xcode9.2.

To solve the problem:
Delete the old one, and install the the New SQLite for Xcode 9
```

Comment: Try cleaning/deleting Derived Data.

Comment: Please advise how? I did Product > Clean, then CMD + B . Result still the same. Please teach me your ways. Thanks

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38016143/3151675

Comment: @the4kman, please see my update.

Comment: @the4kman, thank for your help.  It is working now.