# Xcode project compile error Extracting x86_64 from _ fatal error: lipo: input file _ must be a fat file when the -extract option is specified

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am compiling a iOS project with Xcode 9.3 but same issue on Xcode 9.2
[image]

How can I solve this issue?
I am using cocoapods for these frameworks.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your derived data? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Yes, I deleted the derived data. but same issue.

Comment: I assume you are building for the simulator (hence the need for the x86_64 libs), does it work if you build for a device?  It looks like it is saying that the frameworks don't have the simulator (x86_64) builds.

Comment: I am getting the same error in Xcode 10.1. I have converted my project Xcode 8.1 to Xcode 10.1 and updated all cocoa pods. When I clear derived data then its worked fine for the first time. I am getting an error when running the project the second time. @Popmedic Did you resolved this issue?

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: I think you are using any script and now frameworks embedded through Pod do not need lipo command.