# SDWebImage Error when creating Product Archive for Generic iOS Device

Tags: xcode9, sdwebimage

I've installed SDWebImage into my Xcode project.  The Pod works great, except now I'm ready to create a build of my project and start testing with others using testflight.  When I choose Generic iOS Device and Product -> Archive from xcode, I get the following error:

```
...Frameworks/SDWebImage.framework: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
```

Detailed output below.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Xcode version: Version 9.3 (9E145)
SDWebImage bundle version: 4.2.3

> PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks
>   /Users/tgwagner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/folie-damzcypivcyrbvfnlcuepubrafru/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/folie/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/folie.build/Release-iphoneos/folie.build/Script-D7995652A1B6FAEC372573DE.sh
>       cd /Users/tgwagner/Documents/folie/source/App/folie/folie
>       /bin/sh -c /Users/tgwagner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/folie-damzcypivcyrbvfnlcuepubrafru/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/folie/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/folie.build/Release-iphoneos/folie.build/Script-D7995652A1B6FAEC372573DE.sh
>
> mkdir -p
>   /Users/tgwagner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/folie-damzcypivcyrbvfnlcuepubrafru/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/folie/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/folie.app/Frameworks
>   Symlinked... rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/"
>   --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules"
>   "/Users/tgwagner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/folie-damzcypivcyrbvfnlcuepubrafru/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/folie/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/SDWebImage.framework"
>   "/Users/tgwagner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/folie-damzcypivcyrbvfnlcuepubrafru/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/folie/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//folie.app/Frameworks"
>   building file list ... done SDWebImage.framework/
>   SDWebImage.framework/Info.plist SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage
>
> sent 2547349 bytes  received 70 bytes  5094838.00 bytes/sec total size
>   is 2546802  speedup is 1.00 Stripped
>   /Users/tgwagner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/folie-damzcypivcyrbvfnlcuepubrafru/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/folie/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//folie.app/Frameworks/SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage
>   of architectures: armv7 Code Signing
>   /Users/tgwagner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/folie-damzcypivcyrbvfnlcuepubrafru/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/folie/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//folie.app/Frameworks/SDWebImage.framework
>   with Identity iPhone Developer: Todd Wagner (64J9F8EP32)
>   /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign
>   FA2493469780E25F17F630FF538B8DA75BD6486A 
>   --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/tgwagner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/folie-damzcypivcyrbvfnlcuepubrafru/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/folie/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//folie.app/Frameworks/SDWebImage.framework'
>   /Users/tgwagner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/folie-damzcypivcyrbvfnlcuepubrafru/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/folie/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//folie.app/Frameworks/SDWebImage.framework:
>   unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff Command /bin/sh failed with exit
>   code 1

Comment: try maybe deleting derived data folder? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41039886/5153744

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this.  I had an old version of SDWebImage.  I updated the pod as follows:

pod update SDWebImage

then restarted xcode -- still getting the same error.  Eventually I had to restart computer and everything worked again.

Hope this helps someone else.