# Fabric - Answers not registering on iOS

Tags: ios, google-fabric, fabric-answers

I have configured Answers in my project by adding the following line in app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, Answers.self])
```

I have accepted the terms in the Fabric dashboard and I'm seeing the "Waiting for events" loader. I clean install the app and run it with the debugger attached. The console logs are as follows

```
2018-07-09 16:38:09.876038+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627661] [Crashlytics] Version 3.10.3 (130)
2018-07-09 16:38:09.876290+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627661] [Crashlytics] Running on iOS Simulator (iPhone), 11.4.0 (17F77)
2018-07-09 16:38:09.883163+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627661] [Answers] Initialized
2018-07-09 16:38:09.886097+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627661] [Fabric] Initialized with kit versions: {
    "com.twitter.answers.ios" = "1.3.7";
    "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.10.3";
    "io.fabric.sdk.ios" = "1.7.8";
}
2018-07-09 16:38:10.611174+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627991] [Fabric] settings downloaded successfully
2018-07-09 16:38:10.611995+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627991] [Fabric] Settings are available for consumption
2018-07-09 16:38:10.613082+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627957] [Answers] Answers enabled with settings: {
    "flush_interval_secs" = 10;
    "flush_on_background" = 1;
    "forward_to_google_analytics" = 0;
    "include_purchase_events_in_forwarded_events" = 0;
    "max_byte_size_per_file" = 8000;
    "max_file_count_per_send" = 1;
    "max_pending_send_file_count" = 100;
    "sampling_rate" = 1;
    "track_custom_events" = 1;
    "track_predefined_events" = 1;
    "track_view_controllers" = 0;
    url = "https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events";
}
2018-07-09 16:38:10.627885+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627957] [Answers] Logging events to /Users/nstein/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4659652F-0FF0-4254-B265-A2E54BFAD542/data/Containers/Data/Application/CCD3B822-4E90-4B8A-AA46-713964FC9209/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/myapp/analytics/v2/events
2018-07-09 16:38:10.630927+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627957] [Answers] Transmitting packaged events for 'EB68FA02-082E-463D-A9E1-83FE1A969F10'.
2018-07-09 16:38:10.631427+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627956] [Answers] Transmitting packaged events for '0E388FA3-95FB-4DD1-BC47-E9B1417E27AF'.
2018-07-09 16:38:10.631809+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627957] [Answers] Transmitting packaged events for 'E1FE3C5D-693E-49E4-B8A7-6102EDC76C5C'.
2018-07-09 16:38:11.321912+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627961] [Answers] Finished transmission of 'EB68FA02-082E-463D-A9E1-83FE1A969F10'.
2018-07-09 16:38:11.621711+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627961] [Answers] Finished transmission of '0E388FA3-95FB-4DD1-BC47-E9B1417E27AF'.
2018-07-09 16:38:11.632826+0300 EDBiOS[21729:3627956] [Answers] Finished transmission of 'E1FE3C5D-693E-49E4-B8A7-6102EDC76C5C'.
```

The issue is that the loader never goes away on the dashboard. Answers never seem to be registering. App is running on iOS 11.4 iPhone simulator, Xcode 9.4.1. Used Fabric app on macOS to add frameworks to my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Events..

1. Delete installed app from device, Quit your xcode & delete the [Derived data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49118434/6898523) And Update your pod
2. Now open your project & Clean your Project (**⌘+Option+Shift+K.**)

   for Answer,
   Add `Fabric.with([Answers.self, Crashlytics.self])` in AppDelegate

and Make sure you have added kitName in infoPlist

```
<key>Fabric</key>
    <dict>
        <key>APIKey</key>
        <string>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx46654</string>
        <key>Kits</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
            <key>KitInfo</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>KitName</key>
            <string>Crashlytics</string>
            </dict>
        
        <dict>
            <key>KitInfo</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>KitName</key>
            <string>Answers</string>
        </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

4. Build your Project (**⌘B**)
5. Run the Project

   Now, hard refresh your dashboard in browser

Thanks @[nstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3275792/nstein) for Improving Answer.
[Discussion Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174699/discussion-between-mahipal-singh-and-nstein) for more Help

Comment: Answers KitName is not in my info.plist. Any ideas why?

Comment: I added the Answers dictionary manually as per your suggestion. I also put Answers.self first in the initializer. I clean the project, build it and run it (clean install) on an ipad and the iphone simulator and still it's not registering, no matter how many times I reload the fabric page.

Comment: I'm using logContentView in a certain case and generating crash right after that for test purposes. It seems the event never reaches the dashboard. The crash however does. So on the crashlytics end everything seems fine both on the simulator and the device.

Comment: could open your app for few minutes..may be collected not posted by on server. Just open the application

Comment: I've run it a couple of times with no debugger on the ipad, logging content views.

Comment: Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self]) replace your code line Answer is already inlcuded in Crashlytics

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174699/discussion-between-mahipal-singh-and-nstein).