# XCODE 9 and ionic ios app build failed

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, xcode9

After building the project in ionic v1. I copied project to Mac Pc.
In Mac Pc i deintegrated Podfile and removed Podfile then did pod install.
After that i cleaned project.
When i try to build app it shows linker error.

guys any help appreciated.

Here is my log:

```
Ld /Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Safences\ Resident.build/Debug-iphoneos/Safences\ Resident.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Safences\ Resident normal arm64
cd /Users/inayath/Desktop/safencesResidentAppAndroid/platforms/ios
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk -L/Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac -L/Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Protobuf -L/Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/nanopb -F/Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/inayath/Desktop/safencesResidentAppAndroid/platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/inayath/Desktop/safencesResidentAppAndroid/platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks -F/Users/inayath/Desktop/safencesResidentAppAndroid/platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/inayath/Desktop/safencesResidentAppAndroid/platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Frameworks -filelist /Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Safences\ Resident.build/Debug-iphoneos/Safences\ Resident.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Safences\ Resident.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Safences\ Resident.build/Debug-iphoneos/Safences\ Resident.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Safences\ Resident_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -ObjC -lGoogleToolboxForMac -lProtobuf -lc++ -lnanopb -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AddressBook -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework FirebaseNanoPB -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration /Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a -weak_framework AddressBook -weak_framework AddressBookUI -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreTelephony -weak_framework MessageUI -lPods-Safences\ Resident -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Safences\ Resident.build/Debug-iphoneos/Safences\ Resident.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Safences\ Resident_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Safences\ Resident.build/Debug-iphoneos/Safences\ Resident.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Safences\ Resident

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVLogger in:
    /Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Safences Resident.build/Debug-iphoneos/Safences Resident.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVLogger.o
    /Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a(CDVLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVLogger in:
    /Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Safences Resident.build/Debug-iphoneos/Safences Resident.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVLogger.o
    /Users/inayath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safences_Resident-bohfyzovmoapaxbnzlsayigtqxpl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a(CDVLogger.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the DerivedData and rebuilding? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495772/3959708

Comment: yes i have deleted derived data and rebuild.

Comment: After that i archived the product, after archive organiser window is not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12849#issuecomment-337349446)

> If you use ios 4.5 or higher you need to remove the plugin "cordova-plugin-console" because ios (platform) 4.5 or higher add this plugin by default so you end up with a duplicate error.

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-console
```

should solve your issue.