# QT Creator iOS Error : The settings in the Devices window of Xcode might be incorrect

Tags: ios, qt, qml, qt-creator, porting

I am  trying to run a QT application to iPad.
I could run the same in Mac OS. But, when run with iOS device it is getting an error 'The settings in the Devices window of Xcode might be incorrect'. Please find the attached screenshot.
The iPad is connected successfully.

[image]

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Are you developing a single Window application? or multiple window available in the application?

Comment: I dont know how an app can have multiple "windows", but the problem was solved, though I have not noticed how exactly. I was just trying lots of things to fix it

Answer (score 2):

This problem has happened to me when I changed my info.plist file.
You should manually remove the application on your phone, and install it again using Qt-creator.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you can try to delete the DerivedData folder. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38016143/2229783) for more details.