# Older project stopped building with latest simulator updates

Tags: ios, xcode, build-environment

I have an older project that's using [this method](http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/migrating-ios-app-through-multiple-environments/) to create multiple environments.

It built fine 2 weeks ago.  Today I opened up xcode, it asked to make changes (which were downloading the new simulators), and now the project wont build.

I'm getting this error: 

`error: unable to read property list from file: /Users/{user}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{proj}-axqsdaitnghejddytagzzurgxvka/Build/Intermediates.noindex/{proj}.build/PROD-iphonesimulator/{proj}.build/Preprocessed-Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 0.)`

Literally nothing has changed except the simulator update.  I've checked my build script and everything else.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Try deleting the DerivedData folder: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38016143/3151675

Comment: Did that multiple times 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `-e` is no longer a valid flag so it was printing `-e` in the preprocess.h file and then copying it over to the Preprocess-Info.plist.  Because of this Xcode couldn't open the .plist file and the app wouldn't build.

So I just needed to remove the `-e` flags from all the `echo` statements in the build script.