# Unable to add CocoaPods to Cocoa Touch framework

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am working on a Cocoa Touch framework, which will have a dependency on Alamofire. I am trying to build the framework but it is not building and gives the following error:

> ld: framework not found Alamofire
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**version**

- macOS 10.15.2 (19C57)
- Xcode version 11.3.1
- Swift version 5

[image: Xcode build screenshot]

Comment: just delete derived data from XCODE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-can-i-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8

Comment: Show the content of your Podfile.