# Not allowed to make request to local host - swift

Tags: ios, xcode, security, swift5

I am unable to post to a server in swift 5, XCode Version 11.6 (11E708), and iOS 13.6. I am receiving this error:

```
2020-08-26 08:20:55.252545-0400 iris[1642:721953] Task <BBB3809B-7BEF-4F60-9685-774027ADA7E6>.<1> finished with error [-1022] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x2810ad710 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8000/searchImage/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8000/searchImage/, NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.}
error=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x2810ad710 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8000/searchImage/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8000/searchImage/, NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.}
```

I have followed this question [How can I delete derived data in Xcode 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-can-i-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8) and updated my info.plist

```
<key> App Transport Security Settings </key>
<dict>
    <key> Allow Arbitrary Loads </key>
    <true />
```

Note I don't care about security at this point. Additionally, I've tried a clean build and then deleted my derived data folder, but still I cannot post to the server. In another project I set this key in Info.plist and everything was fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you edit `info.plist` from as source code, to allow all domains, change the values like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/> 
</dict>
```

Then it should look like below as Property List:

[image]

#### or

For a better way, you can disable it by default and add exceptions for specific domains like below.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>yourdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. In addition to adding your suggestions to Info.plist, I had to add the following to the projects entitelments ```com.apple.security.network.server Boolean True``` and ```com.apple.security.network.client Boolean True```

Comment: @sin tribe can you expand on how you do this?

Comment: @David Crook - sorry, I haven't worked with xcode/switft a whole lot since this time and don't really remember.

Comment: No worries, I got it to work.  Can't remember what I did, but its working.

Comment: I am getting the same error even after adding 
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/> 
</dict>

Answer (score 0):

Opened your Project target's info.plist file and added a Key called NSAppTransportSecurity as a Dictionary.

Add NSAllowsArbitraryLoads as Boolean and set its value to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity as like following image - [image]

Comment: Hey Abdul - This looks like a duplicate of the accepted answer.