# XCode Build Phase script exit code 1 error React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am working on a React-Native application. I've inherited it, development has been stopped for a while and some of the dependencies are outdated. I do not believe this is part of the problem but worth mentioning. Whatever I do, both on the command line and in XCode, the build fails with the following error:

```
/bin/sh -c /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-cftpundgcnfgkvchyeqvsgfusuhb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/AppName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.build/Script-948B6EB41D047ADB00584768.sh

Error loading build config, ignoring
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

**What I've done**

- npm install
- In the ios directory, "sudo gem install cocoapods" and "pod install"
- react-native run-ios

One way or another, this never works and the error is always the one above

**What I've tried**

- Locking and unlocking the keychain
- Deleting the derived data folder, cleaning and re-building
- Ticking the "only run for install" checkbox in XCode in the RN bundle section
- Using yarn instead of npm
- pod deintegrate and install once again
- Upgrading react-native

Once more, no luck

I'm fairly new to this and don't fully understand what's going on - or why this is failing. Any ideas as to how to solve it?

**Version info**

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.5
xcode: Version 12.3 (12C33)
simulator: iphone 11 (ios 14.3)

Comment: Try to delete the content of the  DerivedData folder see - https://programmingwithswift.com/delete-derived-data-xcode/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-can-i-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8 for more info

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer - but as the question states, I've already tried to delete the derived data folder (and also cleaned the project) to no avail

Comment: This isn't really the error. try running the app via xCode and check the error again

Comment: Hi, again, as the question states, this error happens both in the command line and in Xcode.

Comment: Ha, I missed that part you are right, In this case try to go to the build phases of your xcode project and understand which scripts are running during build... try remove them one by. one and see if the problem is resolved, maybe like. you said on of your dependencies is running some old script...