# How do I resolve Trace/BPT Trap: 5 errors in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-m1

I'm building an app on an M1 Mac. I added a pod, Swift Package, or framework, attempted to use an object from it, and when I built my project, received this error. I've tried a number of things including changing build settings and deleting the derived data folder. The problem persists no matter what I try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Firebase with Swift packages (and I have the m1), and this resolved the issue for me:

`File -> Swift Packages -> Reset Package Caches`

I did this after a hard restart and cleaning the build folder. All good now.

Comment: This normally fixes the problem and derived data only needs to be cleared sometimes, so I'm making this the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to occur when a pod or framework isn't ready for the M1 processor yet. Resolving the error varies depending on if it's a pod or framework/Swift Package. Once you remove the offending package/framework/pod, it may be worth trying again if you really need it, sometimes the bug is intermittent.

#### Either Method (do this first!)

Sometimes this error is resolved without removing a pod or framework.

1. [Clear your Derived Data folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-can-i-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8)
2. Clean the build folder with `shift+cmd+k`

#### Cocoapods

It seems to be necessary to deintegrate pods, remove the `Podfile.lock`, take the offending pod out of your `Podfile`, and reinstall pods.

##### From Terminal:

```sh
pod deintegrate
rm Podfile.lock
nano Podfile
```

`nano` can be replaced with your text editor of choice. You just need to remove the offending Pod

```sh
pod install
```

#### Framework/Swift Package

1. Click on your project file in Xcode (the blue icon)
2. With the target selected that contains the framework, click on General
3. Scroll down to `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`
4. Click on the offending Framework
5. Click on the minus icon at the bottom of the list
6. Click `Delete` in the confirmation dialogue

#### Finish Up

No matter the method you choose, it's a good idea to:

1. [Clear your Derived Data folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-can-i-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8)
2. Clean the build folder with `shift+cmd+k`
3. Reach out to the framework/pod author and ask them to update it for M1 support
4. [File a bug report with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)