# Touchlab Xcode-plugin for debugging KMM project in XCode is not working

Tags: xcode, kotlin, debugging, kotlin-multiplatform

This plugin https://github.com/touchlab/xcode-kotlin doesn’t allow to debug kotlin code through Xcode, files are not colored and there is no possibility to add a breakpoint in kotlin files (though it is for .swift files), what to do?

Comment: Super confused. It looks like you asked the question then answered yourself immediately?

Comment: StackOver provides us with an option to reply to your own questions.

Comment: @KevinGalligan Yes, spent some time figuring out how to make things with plugin work and decided to share knowledge here :) If you want to try this option - when ask questions just tick an option **"Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style"**

Comment: I know you can answer your own question, but it seemed like you did it immediately. That was the confusing part for me :) If you have an other issues, let us know (SO or github issues)

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that you follow all the steps mentioned in `readme`:

- Download project from GitHub and run `./setup.sh` plugin (or `./setup-xcode11.sh` for newer versions https://github.com/touchlab/xcode-kotlin/pull/30/files)
- Open Xcode and go to “Show project navigator”, create a new group there (mine is under the `executive-app`)
- Add `commonMain` and `iosMain` folders to the newly created group

2. If the steps above still don’t help, try to restart Xcode, restart the computer or delete `DerivedData` [How can I delete derived data in Xcode 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-can-i-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8)
3. **Important!** If you have **several Xcode versions** or if you have recently **updated your Xcode**, probably plugin does not know your Xcode UUID.

To make plugin know about it try:

- get UUID manually: `defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID` (if you have several version it will probably something like `defaults read /Applications/<howMyXCodeIsNamed>.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID`)
- write this UUID to plugin info file defaults `write ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Plug-ins/Kotlin.ideplugin/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs -array-add <UUID from previous step>`

Or use this https://github.com/touchlab/xcode-kotlin/pull/29/files to correct the initial script, but before please make sure that Xcode version you are now using is default (it could be set by `sudo xcode-select --switch Applications/path/to/your/xcode`)