# react native - 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a simple React native application and getting the below error after doing `pod install` and doing `npm run ios`. I have tried solutions from similar questions in SO. My context is different as it is finding duplicate symbol in `Build/Intermediates.noindex/` and `Build/Products/`. The library which is showing error is `"react-native-share": "^7.4.1"`

```
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_RNShare' in:
    /Users/r0g05wc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Aws-fsudfklafeulphhdpwjqdjzyeavw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Aws.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Aws.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNShare-ec270c8f2fdfe4cae64d418fb1db2df0.o
    /Users/r0g05wc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Aws-fsudfklafeulphhdpwjqdjzyeavw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNShare/libRNShare.a(RNShare.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_RNShare' in:
    /Users/r0g05wc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Aws-fsudfklafeulphhdpwjqdjzyeavw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Aws.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Aws.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNShare-ec270c8f2fdfe4cae64d418fb1db2df0.o
    /Users/r0g05wc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Aws-fsudfklafeulphhdpwjqdjzyeavw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNShare/libRNShare.a(RNShare.o)
```

Comment: Try deleting XCode derived data and re run the project
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41039886/10847604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the issue was an extra `RNShare.m` file in the ios folder. I deleted it and it worked.