# XCode "No such file or directory" error after project name change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm building my first iOS app in xcode. I have a pretty simple app currently set up, and it was building correctly with no issues. Then I wanted to check how easy it would be to update the project name, since we are currently working with a placeholder project name.

I'm pretty sure that this is where I messed the project up, unless I'm forgetting something. I updated the "Display Name" under general settings for the project, and ever since that I get four different compilation errors about `no such file or directory` being found.

Here's one of them, the rest all have very similar file paths:

```
error: /Users/laika/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ios-ctnppilmitfbrnfexnoxivnafaey/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp-ios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp-ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/myapp-Swift.h: No such file or directory (in target 'myapp-ios' from project 'myapp-ios')
```

None of the files are any of the files I've coded it's just these `debug-iphonsimulator` files, and none of them are referenced in any of the code I wrote.

I changed the display name back to what it was before these issues started popping up, but I still get these missing file issues! I don't know where to update these filepaths, and even if I did know where, I don't know what I should update them TO. Does anyone have any guidance?

Thank you!

Comment: Since the file path is pointing to Derived Data, you could try to delete Derived Data (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-can-i-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8)