# Build Failed when running react-native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, macos, google-signin

Build failed - I don't know what's the problem is, I just want to apply `google-sign-in` in my app using firebase, I already applied the setup of `iOS` through this documentation [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/google-login-with-react-native-and-firebase/) but when I run `npx react-native run-ios` I have this error below, can anyone help me with this, it's very helpful for me because I've been stack with this problem.

What I do is I've added this in my `podfile`

```
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
```

**AppDelegate.m** I added it

```
#import <Firebase.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil){
    [FIRApp configure];
  }
```

**Error**

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with 

error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening finds.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace finds.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme finds -destination id=F2DA8402-50E9-481E-A93D-2AA94FAE73D4

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

note: Using new build system
note: Planning
Analyze workspace

Create build description
Build description signature: 98943ed3bd8b83f0e649a4dd42f8e14d
Build description path: /Users/macky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/finds-cguyzegrdhdxxtdlttykzqdduzdc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/98943ed3bd8b83f0e649a4dd42f8e14d-desc.xcbuild

note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
error: unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database "/Users/macky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/finds-cguyzegrdhdxxtdlttykzqdduzdc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/build.db": database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location.

2022-07-26 16:36:27.812 xcodebuild[19232:242056] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-07-26 16:36:27.812 xcodebuild[19232:242056] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
** BUILD FAILED **
```

and I install `pod install`

Comment: Can anyone knows the solution? need help

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495772/4781064) helps

Comment: @sushrut619 should I delete the entire `DerivedData` folder? should it safe to delete?

Comment: @sushrut619 I tried deleting the project folder in derivedData but the error is the same